# Как задать адаптивную верстку блоку на html и .scss?

Tags: html, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, scss

Есть блок из шести подблоков, которые расположены по  два в ряду.

[image: Блоки]

Как и где, с помощью свойства `max-width`, задать нужное значение, чтобы при просмотре на экране шириной `700px` отображение блоков стало в один столбец (из шести блоков, один под другим)?

Т.е. я изменю масштаб окна браузера и при этом увижу один целый столбец из картинок.

```css
.solutions {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.solutions .hover-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  background: transparent url("../images/prod-bg-hover.png");
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 21px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.solutions .hover-block h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'DINPro-Black', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 58px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 124px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.solutions .hover-block h3.small {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.solutions .hover-block p {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.solutions .container-solutions a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.solutions .container-solutions a:hover img, .solutions .container-solutions a:focus img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) 500ms;
}
.solutions .container-solutions a:hover .hover-block, .solutions .container-solutions a:focus .hover-block {
  opacity: 1;
}
.solutions .flex-column {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.solutions .flex-center-column {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.solutions .flex-center-column a {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="solutions" class="section solutions">
        <div class="title-section-wrap bg-title-green">
            <div class="title-section-text container">Наши решения</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container container-solutions">
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="flex-center-column">
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <a>
                            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
                            <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3>Promo Face</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Вспомогательная программа, позволяющая отслеживать<br/>
                                    эффективность и осуществлять контроль<br/>
                                    работы над промо-персоналом.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a>
                            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
                            <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3 class="small">Корпоративный университет </h3>
                                <p>
                                    Виртуальный портал для дистанционного обучения и
                                    развития сотрудников, а также для ознакомления
                                    со структурой и внутренним взаимодействием
                                    в Компании.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <a>
                            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
                            <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3>CRM-Promo</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Cистема с возможностью интеграции с сайтом, социальными
                                    медиа, инструментами распознавания QR кодов и т.д.
                                    позволяющая собирать показатели об эффективности
                                    проводимой промоакции.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a >
                            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
                            <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3 class="small">DIGITAL SAMPLING</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Возможность интеграции в Интернет-магазины для
                                    предложения пользователям семплингов
                                    (вложений) к совершенным покупкам.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <a>
                            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
                            <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3 class="small">Программа Лояльности</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Мотивационная программа для стимулирования сотрудников
                                    к повышению показателей с возможным
                                    дальнейшим награждением.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a>
                            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
                            <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3>Library</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Программа для информирования мерчендайзеров и
                                    сотрудников торговых точек/учреждений о
                                    новых продуктах и изменениях.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: как сделать это?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте этот код в конец css файла

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .flex-row {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .solutions .flex-row a {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```css
.solutions {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.solutions .hover-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  background: transparent url("../images/prod-bg-hover.png");
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 21px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.solutions .hover-block h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'DINPro-Black', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 58px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 124px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.solutions .hover-block h3.small {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.solutions .hover-block p {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.solutions .container-solutions a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.solutions .container-solutions a:hover img,
.solutions .container-solutions a:focus img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) 500ms;
}

.solutions .container-solutions a:hover .hover-block,
.solutions .container-solutions a:focus .hover-block {
  opacity: 1;
}

.solutions .flex-column {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.solutions .flex-center-column {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.solutions .flex-center-column a {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .flex-row {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .solutions .flex-row a {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="solutions" class="section solutions">
  <div class="title-section-wrap bg-title-green">
    <div class="title-section-text container">Наши решения</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container container-solutions">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="flex-center-column">
        <div class="flex-row">
          <a>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3>Promo Face</h3>
              <p>
                Вспомогательная программа, позволяющая отслеживать<br/> эффективность и осуществлять контроль<br/> работы над промо-персоналом.
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3 class="small">Корпоративный университет </h3>
              <p>
                Виртуальный портал для дистанционного обучения и развития сотрудников, а также для ознакомления со структурой и внутренним взаимодействием в Компании.
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <a>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3>CRM-Promo</h3>
              <p>
                Cистема с возможностью интеграции с сайтом, социальными медиа, инструментами распознавания QR кодов и т.д. позволяющая собирать показатели об эффективности проводимой промоакции.
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3 class="small">DIGITAL SAMPLING</h3>
              <p>
                Возможность интеграции в Интернет-магазины для предложения пользователям семплингов (вложений) к совершенным покупкам.
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <a>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3 class="small">Программа Лояльности</h3>
              <p>
                Мотивационная программа для стимулирования сотрудников к повышению показателей с возможным дальнейшим награждением.
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3>Library</h3>
              <p>
                Программа для информирования мерчендайзеров и сотрудников торговых точек/учреждений о новых продуктах и изменениях.
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю! у меня в исходниках только .scss . тоже сработает?

Comment: @DmitryNikitin, да

Comment: этот вариант не работает. всё осталось как прежде.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin, вариант рабочий, я просто не учел спецефичность селекторов. Обновил ответ и добавил пример. Но, дам еще один совет. Перепишите свой код, у вас полный бардак. Половину узлов(оберток) можно убрать + упростить спецефичность селекторов.

Comment: если в Москве живёте, есть возможность встречи (30 минут хотя бы)? Буду пробовать, надеюсь на лучшее, испытательный срок...

Comment: @DmitryNikitin, Я не живу в Мск.